# Web application with c# language, Master page

Tags: web-applications, master-pages

how can i select masterpage2 for my page whereas my page in run time mode and already use masterpage1?

Comment: Could you rewrite your question please? It's hard to understand at the moment.

Comment: I guess you want to runtime changing the masterpage of your .aspx from 1 to 2, right? What's the reason behind such kind of changing? Since masterpage is a way to define the structure of pages, and changing it (even it can) may break that kind of structure. If you looking for skinning, consider dynamic injected CSS or Themes.

Answer (score 1):

After a small search on [google](http://www.google.com) I found the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Changing_Master_Page.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just so the code is *here* for anyone who finds this question: (Adapted from @Shaharyar's link)

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
 if () { //check for anything you like..

     this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/General.master"; 
 } 
  else {
     this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/myMaster.master";
 }
}
```